# My setter won't return 0 when an int is out of bounds of my else-if statement

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, constructor

My constructors are supposed to return the score given as long as the score is from 0 to 300. If the score is outside this boundary, a value of 0 should be returned. However, it instead returns the value of what i gave my class, rather than what I set. 
Main Program

```
namespace ClassScores
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             int runningTotal = 0;
             double average = 0;
             .....
             Bowler Jesus = new Bowler("Jesus", 450);
             bowlers[3] = Jesus;
             for (int i=0; i <= 4; i++)
             {
             runningTotal=runningTotal + bowlers[i].Score;
             }
             average = Convert.ToDouble(runningTotal/5);
             Console.WriteLine("The average bowler score is " + average);

         }
     }
 }
```

Class

```
namespace ClassScores
{
     class Bowler

     {
         private string name;
         private int score;
         public string Name
         {
          .....
         }
         public int Score
         {
             get
             {
                 return this.score;
             }
             set
             {
                 if (Score>=0 && Score <=300)
                 {
                     this.score = value;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     this.score = 0;
                 }
             }
         }

         public Bowler (string name, int score)
         {
             this.Name = name;
             this.Score = score;
         }
         public string ToString()
         {
             return (Name + " has a score of " + Convert.ToString(Score) + "  points.");
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not range-checking `value`, which is the new value. You're range-checking `Score` -- the *old* value. This is what you intended to do:

```
     set
     {
         if (value >= 0 && value <= 300)
         {
             this.score = value;
         }
         else
         {
             this.score = 0;
         }
     }
```

I'm guessing this was just absent-mindedness.

### UPDATE

You could do the same thing less verbosely:

```
     set
     {
         this.score = (value >= 0 && value <= 300)
                          ? value
                          : 0;
     }
```

...but if that looks like line noise to you, stick with what you've got!

Another thing I'd suggest is renaming `score` to `_score`. That's the C# convention for private fields, and it prevents you from ever accidentally setting `score` when you really wanted to set `Score`.

Comment: Using the `?:` operator here would be nice